# Why is h*= h* 101 + s[i] and h = h * 101 + s[i] different in this case?

Tags: c++, key, hash-function

I am just curious why would the two functions produce different results.

```
unsigned long Hash1(const string s)
{

    int length = s.length();
    unsigned long h = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        h *= 101 + (unsigned long)s[i];

    return h;
}

unsigned long Hash2(const string s)
{

    int length = s.length();
    unsigned long h = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        h = h * 101 + (unsigned long)s[i];

    return h;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Value of hash1 = " << Hash1("kelvin@gmail.com") << endl;
    cout << "Value of hash2 = " << Hash2("kelvin@gmail.com") << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Isn't `h *= 101 + (unsigned long)s[i]` equals `to h = h * 101 + (unsigned long)s[i]`?

This is the output:

Value of *hash1* = `1693843456`

Value of *hash2* = `2162085645`

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: You don't have `h*= 101` or `h = h * 101`. You have `h *= 101 + (unsigned long)s[i]` and `h = h * 101 + (unsigned long)s[i]`.

Comment: You're actually telling it..`h = h * (101 + s[i])`.. In other words, h = itself multiplied by the entire right side expression.

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't `h *= 101 + (unsigned long)s[i]` equals to `h = h * 101 + (unsigned long)s[i]`?

No, due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `h *= 101 + (unsigned long)s[i]` is equivalent to `h *= (101 + (unsigned long)s[i])`, which is the same as `h = h * (101 + (unsigned long)s[i])`.

The difference between the two is the difference between computing:

```
h = h*(a+b)
```

and

```
h = h*a + b
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers are already given in the comments to the question, but just to expand on the question, the two *statements*

```
h *= 101;

h = h * 101;
```

are indeed equivalent. But when used inside of larger *expressions*, `*=` has very low precedence. `*` has the highest precedence, then `+`, then `*=`. So

```
h *= 101 + x;
```

is the same as:

```
h = h * (101 + x);
```

Now, if you *wanted*

```
h = (h * 101) + x;
```

you could have written:

```
(h *= 101) += x;
```

which works because the `*=` operator returns a reference to the left hand side. However, this doesn't really look great.